# How to import a Tag from the first file to all Tag In the second file

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, getelementsbytagname

How to import a Tag "mohamed" From the first file to all TAG ahmed In the second file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9        http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->


<mohamed>stackover flow</mohamed>
</map>
```

My Xml-2 file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->

<ahmed></ahmed>
<ahmed></ahmed>
<ahmed></ahmed>

</map>
```

enter code here

With these pieces i can import TagName("mohamed") to the TagName("ahmed") First only
I want to import it into every TagName("ahmed") In the second file

```
public static void t (int f ,  int g,String z) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = null;
    Document doc = null;
    Document doc2 = null;
String a = "C:\\Users\\chirap\\Desktop\\Startimes\\C.txt" ;
String  c ;
    try {
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = db.parse(new File(a));

            doc2 = db.parse(new File("C:\\Users\\chirap\\Desktop\\Startimes\\A (1).txt"));
            NodeList ndListFirstFile = doc.getElementsByTagName("ahmed");

            Node nodeArea = doc.importNode(doc2.getElementsByTagName("mohamed").item(0), true);


        NodeList nList2 = doc2.getElementsByTagName("mohamed");

            for (int i = f; i <g; i++) {
                c = i+"" ;
               doc2 = db.parse(new File("C:\\Users\\chirap\\Desktop\\Startimes\\A ("+c+").txt"));

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList2.getLength(); temp++) {

                nodeArea = doc.importNode(doc2.getElementsByTagName("mohamed").item(temp), true);
                   ndListFirstFile.item(0).appendChild(nodeArea);
```

The result now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->

<ahmed><mohamed>stackover flow</mohamed></ahmed>
<ahmed></ahmed>
<ahmed></ahmed>

</map>
```

I want this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->

    <ahmed><mohamed>stackover flow</mohamed></ahmed>
    <ahmed><mohamed>stackover flow</mohamed></ahmed>
    <ahmed><mohamed>stackover flow</mohamed></ahmed>

    </map>
```

Comment: Why does the `XML` file have a `.txt` extension?

Comment: They are the same thing

Comment: No, they aren't, though it doesn't matter for the above. Separately: When asking for help, please use meaningful method and variable names, not `t`, `f`, `g`, etc.  (It's a good idea when you're *not* asking for help, too.)

Comment: `doc.querySelector("mohamed").textContent`

Comment: Content is the most important and yet this can change between two extensions xml or txt

Comment: Where is the change?

Comment: Re _"I want this result"_ `let el = doc.querySelector("mohamed"); let parentElement = el.parentElement; let text = el.textContent; parentElement.removeChild(el); parentElement.textContent = text;`

Comment: I want you to give me a result in full code

Comment: Where do I change?

Comment: @AmiraSki What do you want to change and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this

```
try {
     File inputOne = new File("first.xml");
     File inputTwo = new File("second.xml");

     DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document docOne = dBuilder.parse(inputOne);
     Document docTwo = dBuilder.parse(inputTwo);
     NodeList nodeListAhmed = docTwo.getElementsByTagName("ahmed");

     for (int i = 0; i < nodeListAhmed.getLength(); i++) {
         Node nodeMohamed = docTwo.importNode(docOne.getElementsByTagName("mohamed").item(0), true);
         nodeListAhmed.item(i).appendChild(nodeMohamed);
     }

     DOMSource source = new DOMSource(docTwo);
     TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
     Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
     StreamResult result = new StreamResult("output.xml");
     transformer.transform(source, result);

} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you that the method works but between two files only
I wished it did not modify the program to comply with working on several files such as if there are the following files: C (1).xml C (2).xml C (3).xml .....

Answer (score 0):

> I want this result
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <ahmed
>       xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
>       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
>             http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
> <!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->
>
>
> stackover flow
> </ahmed>
> ```

You can use `.querySelector()` to get the element having `tagName` `"mohamed"`, store `.parentElement` of the element in a variable, store the `.textContent` of the matched elements in a variable, remove the matched element from parent element using `.removeChild()`, set the parent element `.textContent` to the stored variable

```js
const xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ahmed
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9        http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->


<mohamed>stackover flow</mohamed>
</ahmed>`;
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
let el = doc.querySelector("mohamed");
let parentElement = el.parentElement;
let text = el.textContent;
parentElement.removeChild(el);
parentElement.textContent = text;
console.log(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>${doc.documentElement.outerHTML}`);
```

Comment: @AmiraSki Not sure what you mean? Nothing is stopping you from editing the code.Why do you want to edit the code that outputs the requirement described at the original question?

Comment: @AmiraSki Ok. That requirement does not appear at the original question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What issues are you having achieving that additional requirement?

Comment: @ guest271314 @ guest271314  guest271314@The question has been redrafted
Can you help now?

Comment: @Rathnayake  Rathnayake@ @ Rathnayake