# import Tag Text Content Instead of full Tag in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, getelementsbytagname

I need a simple Java code modification to import only the text content of an XML element instead of the entire element.

How can I get only the value of the tag name using `getElementsByTagName()`?

This is the XML file I am reading named **A (1).xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <site
          xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9        http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->

    <map>I want to import this content only</map>
    </site>
```

Note that the file contains a `<map>` element one line from the end.

This is the content of the XML file I am writing to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <tap
          xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
                http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->

    <site>I do not want to lose this content </site>
</tap>
```

I want to extract the text value of TagName("map"), but not the tags themselves, and write that text to file shown above. This is my code:

```
package startimes;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import java.io.*;

public class Startimes {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        int r = 1;
        int l = 1;
        int s = 1;
        String nom;
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
            nom = "B (" + (i + 1);
            t(r, r + l, nom);
            r = r + l;
        }
    }

    public static void t(int f, int g, String z) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = null;
        Document doc = null;
        Document doc2 = null;
        String a = "C:\\Users\\chirap\\Desktop\\Startimes\\C.xml";
        String c;
        try {
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = db.parse(new File(a));
            doc2 = db.parse(new File("C:\\Users\\chirap\\Desktop\\Startimes\\A (1).xml"));
            NodeList ndListFirstFile = doc.getElementsByTagName("site");
            Node nodeArea = doc.importNode(doc2.getElementsByTagName("map").item(0), true);
            NodeList nList2 = doc2.getElementsByTagName("map");
            for (int i = f; i < g; i++) {
                c = i + "";
                doc2 = db.parse(new File("C:\\Users\\chirap\\Desktop\\Startimes\\A (" + c + ").xml"));
                for (int temp = 0; temp < nList2.getLength(); temp++) {
                    nodeArea = doc.importNode(doc2.getElementsByTagName("map").item(temp), true);
                    ndListFirstFile.item(0).appendChild(nodeArea);
                }
            }
            TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
            transformer.transform(source, result);
            Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\chirap\\Desktop\\Startimes\\" + z + ").xml"));
            String xmlOutput = result.getWriter().toString();
            output.write(xmlOutput);
            output.close();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I want this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tap
xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
                        http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->

<site>I do not want to lose this content 
I want to import this content only</site>

</tap>
```

Note that the last line but one should only contain text, but when I run my code it looks like this:

```
<map>I want to import this content only</map>
```

I want to exclude those `<map>` tags. Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Any number of causes may contribute to your problem being unresolved - let me start with some you can do something about. `Tag Text Content Instead of full Tag How to …` - that is a lot of capital letters I can't see a reason for; and a full-stop seems to be missing where you put a line break "in the post edit window". As you can see, no-one can see that line break without going out of her way: just append two blanks to a line when you want the next line to start at the start of a line. Heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: See [ask]. You should also tell us what results you  _do_ get. It also looks like you need to debug your own code, because SO is a terrible debugger. Few are going to try and make sense of that blob of source, so you are going to have to show what you have tried.

Comment: I put the whole program up and it works fine and now I want to adjust it

Comment: it is realy hard to read that code :/ 
for (int i = f; i <g; i++) {
                c = i+"" ;

i dont know what does what :( 

And in few weeks, you wil don't know that ether :) 

What about giving them longer, self describing names :) ?

like "index,type, numberOfBones" what so ever :D 

And not putting everything in same one big method, but splitting them in smaller methods, so that you can test the functionality of small code parts, insted of big blob :) ?

Comment: @AmiraSki I modified your post to format the Java, and clarify the problem. Please review my changes carefully in case I misunderstood anything.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <site
          xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
                http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->

   <site> </site></tap>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this,

```
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList2.getLength(); temp++) {
    ndListFirstFile.item(0).setTextContent(ndListFirstFile.item(0).getTextContent()+nodeArea.getTextContent());
}
```

Comment: There are no mistakes but give us the same result as loss of content of tag </site>

Comment: what is the file (second file) name?

Comment: (second file) name is A (1) ==> A (" + c + ")  and First File name is C

Comment: please share the second file (C.xml)

Comment: the file (C.xml) <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <tap xmlns="sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"> <!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com --> <site>I do not want to lose this content </site> </tap>

Comment: please try with above modified answer

Comment: I have another question with the same program here      
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54854849/how-to-import-a-tag-from-the-first-file-to-all-tag-in-the-second-file   
If you want help and be thankful to you

Comment: @AmiraSki if the above solution works, please upvote :-) Thanks!

Comment: yes it works for (int temp = 0; temp < nList2.getLength(); temp++) {  nodeArea = doc.importNode(doc2.getElementsByTagName("map").item(temp), true); ndListFirstFile.item(0).setTextContent(ndListFirstFile.item(0).getTextContent()+nodeArea.getTextContent());
}

Comment: //////////////////////

Answer (score 0):

`ndListFirstFile.item(0).appendChild(nodeArea);` code append `<map>` child element with it's value under the `<site>` parent element. output as follows,

```
<site .......................>
    <map>I want to import this content only</map>
</site>
```

set the content only (value of the `</map>` element) to `<site>` element, try with this

```
ndListFirstFile.item(0).setTextContent(nodeArea.getTextContent());
```

output

```
<site .......................>I want to import this content only</site>
```

Comment: True 100/100 Thank you brother brought me out of a difficult problem
I do not know what I'm saying to you and thank you again and again

Comment: friend's problem arose
When I add this ndListFirstFile.item(0).setTextContent(nodeArea.getTextContent());
The content of the tag is imported from the second file but I lose the content of the tag from the first file

Comment: Rathnayake@ Rathnayake@Rathnayake@Rathnayake@

Comment: please refer a below answer

Comment: the file (C.xml) <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <tap
          xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
                http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->

   <site>I do not want to lose this content </site>   </tap>

Comment: @ Rathnayake  Rathnayake@ I have another question with the same program here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54854849/how-to-import-a-tag-from-the-first-file-to-all-tag-in-the-second-file  If you want help and be thankful to you

Comment: @ Rathnayake ؟؟؟؟